# In Angular 2 - override/eliminate the custom element?

Tags: angular

So I've been playing with Angular 2 components, and I notice that components need a selector, IE: `my-component`. I may have a component where outputting a custom element is undesirable (ie: I just want to output a div, but I don't want the consumer to worry about which element I am outputting).

Is it possible with Angular 2 to output only the template, and remove or override the custom element?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html)?

Comment: Or something like structural directive such as *ng-if https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#star-template

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks but I don't think directive fits since I do want a component with a template, it's just that the wrapping tag should be determined by the consumer, not the predefined selector. One way I found to achieve this is by using an HTML5 data attribute selector.

Comment: @Chandermani looks to me like structural directive is not much different than Directive with respect to my problem/solution, though it's definitely an interesting idea. I do want an element, I just want the consumer to specify it - or possibly have it dynamically generated by the component - rather than specified by the predefined selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and found that I could have the parent component specify the wrapper element by using the attribute selector on the child component instead of element selector:

```
@Component({ selector: '[custom-attribute]' })
```

If you call this with:

```
<div custom-attribute></div>
```

It will inject the @View of your child component inside your div rather than wrapping it in `<custom-attribute></custom-attribute>`

Comment: That's a neat trick to solve this problem. Sometimes the custom element doesn't work well with some CSS styling and this solves this.